# Comparing Boost.Fiber with Goroutines correct usability

Tags: c++, boost, goroutine, boost-fiber

Good day,

Well, I know there are already some discussions about comparison on Boost.Fiber and Goroutines. But as a new developer in the concurrency space, I am quite confused on the difference and usability.

So currently, I am doing some Go to C++ migration, and some of my roadblocks are the use of Channels and Goroutines, so I did some minor reading on concurrency, Boost.Fiber, and Goroutines and made a sample implementation based on what I understand about the topic.

```golang
package main

import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

const (
    timeout    = 0
    interrupt  = 1
    serverDone = 2
)

func runDurationTimer(d time.Duration, toStop chan int) {
    go func() {
        dSeconds := uint64(d.Seconds())
        if dSeconds == 0 {
            return
        }
        time.Sleep(d)
        toStop <- timeout
    }()
}

func clientWatchControlChannel(d time.Duration, toStop chan int) {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(d)
        toStop <- serverDone
    }()
}

func main() {
    toStop := make(chan int, 1)
    d := 5 * time.Second
    runDurationTimer(d, toStop)
    clientWatchControlChannel(1 * time.Second, toStop)

    fmt.Println("Hello World \n")

    reason := <-toStop
    switch reason {
    case timeout:
        fmt.Println("Process done, duration: " + d.String() +".")
    case interrupt:
        fmt.Println("Process done, received interrupt signal.")
    case serverDone:
        fmt.Println("Process done, server terminated the session.")
    }
}
```

So the code above is a basic success and timeout scheme, where when a function fails to return a status on within a certain duration it times out.

For `clientWatchControlChannel` in real scenario, the `Sleep` would be some other process that needs to return something and finish the procedure. Basinf on the hard coded values, the whole program returns `"Process done, server terminated the session."`, because the duration of running `clientWatchControlChannel` is < the timeout value in `runDurationTimer`.

So when I debugged the code, it runs the 2 procedures, so I placed a breakpoint at `toStop <- timeout` and `toStop <- serverDone`, so `runDurationTimer` runs then sleeps then while waiting to finish it runs `clientWatchControlChannel` then finishes first since it has lesser duration than `runDurationTimer`, after this, it doesn't go back to `runDurationTimer` and wait, it just terminates and assign the value for output.

In my understanding in C++, I have coded the following.

```cpp
#include <boost/fiber/all.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::fibers::unbuffered_channel<int> unbuffered_channel_t;

enum stop { timeout = 0, interrupt, serverDone };

void runDurationTimer(
    const std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>> &d,
    unbuffered_channel_t &toStop) {
  boost::fibers::async([&]() {
    if (d.count() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    boost::this_fiber::sleep_for(d);
    toStop.push(timeout);
  });
}

void clientWatchChannel(
    const std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>> &d,
    unbuffered_channel_t &toStop) {
  boost::fibers::async([&]() {
    boost::this_fiber::sleep_for(d);
    toStop.push(serverDone);
  });
}

int main() {
  unbuffered_channel_t chan;
  auto dTime = std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>>(3);
  auto dWatch = std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>>(1);

  runDurationTimer(dTime, chan);
  clientWatchChannel(dWatch, chan);

  std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

  int i = 0;
  chan.pop(i);


  switch (i) {
  case timeout:
    std::cout << "Process done, duration: " << std::to_string(dTime.count())
              << ".";
    break;
  case interrupt:
    std::cout << "Process done, received interrupt signal.";
    break;
  case serverDone:
    std::cout << "Process done, server terminated the session.";
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So to cut the long story short, everything was nearly the same in behaviour. Again, I debugged the code, placed breakpoints in `toStop.push(serverDone);` and `toStop.push(timeout);`, so the same with Go, it ran `runDurationTimer` first then while waiting for it to finish `clientWatchControlChannel` kicks in and ran `toStop.push(serverDone);`, but the difference is instead of terminating, it went back to `runDurationTimer` and ran `toStop.push(timeout);`. So I think this is the thing that I am really confused. Then `chan.pop(i)` returned `serverDone`.

So, I really need some help on my understanding if its correct or not, or should I continue using Boost.Fiber for this Go migration or use Boost.Coroutines2. Any suggestions, reactions, and corrections are appreciated, I am willing to learn from this.

My apologies on my C++ as well, been along time stagnating. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to close the channel

```
 #include <boost/fiber/all.hpp>
 #include <chrono>
 #include <iostream>

 typedef boost::fibers::unbuffered_channel<int> unbuffered_channel_t;

 enum stop { timeout = 0, interrupt, serverDone };

 void runDurationTimer(
     const std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>> &d,
     unbuffered_channel_t &toStop) {
   boost::fibers::async([&]() {
     if (d.count() == 0) {
       return;
     }
     boost::this_fiber::sleep_for(d);
     // return value would indicate that the channel was closed
     // `timeout` will not be inserted into the channel
     toStop.push(timeout);
   });
 } 

 void clientWatchChannel(
     const std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>> &d,
     unbuffered_channel_t &toStop) {
   boost::fibers::async([&]() {
     boost::this_fiber::sleep_for(d);
     toStop.push(serverDone);
     toStop.close();
   });
  } 

  int main() {
   unbuffered_channel_t chan; 
   auto dTime = std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>>(3);
   auto dWatch = std::chrono::duration<std::uint32_t, std::ratio<1, 1>>(1);

   runDurationTimer(dTime, chan);
   clientWatchChannel(dWatch, chan);

   std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

   int i = 0;
   chan.pop(i);         

   switch (i) {
   case timeout:
     std::cout << "Process done, duration: " << std::to_string(dTime.count())
               << ".";
     break;
   case interrupt:
     std::cout << "Process done, received interrupt signal.";
     break;
   case serverDone:
     std::cout << "Process done, server terminated the session.";
     break;
   default:
     break;
   }
   std::cout << "\n";
   return 0;
  }
```

> Hello, World!
>
> Process done, server terminated the session.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I agree that the channel should be closed after one thread returns, but if you debug the code, after `clientWatchChannel` has finished it and goes back to `runDurationTimer` which has a different behavior of the Goroutine + channels. The `Goroutine` finishes the whole process once `clientWatchChannel` has finished and doesn't wait for `runDurationTimer`.

Comment: boost::fiber != Goroutine (boost.fiber are userland threads with an API like std::thread)
I don't see any reason why the fiber spawned by clientWatchChannel() should terminate the process (there is no glue code that would indicate it).